# SoapUi and Rest WS, how to pass JSon?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, soapui

I'm pretty new with Rest WS

I try to create a Rest WS in which i'd like to pass some Json :

```
{
 name: "conversation.start",
 datetime: {
    created: "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
    sent: "2014-01-01 00:00:01"
 },
 parameters: {
    conversation_id: 1,
    type:            "chat|call|video",
    operator_id:     1,
    website_id:      1,
    group_id:        1,
    custom_data:     {
        example:     "value"
    }
 }
}
```

My WS:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("push")
public Response push(@RequestParam("CustomData") String text) {

    ....

    return null;
}
```

But i can't figure out what and how to pass my Json structure with SoapUI, my string text is always null or  ""
Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

The below link helps you working with REST in soapui
http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/working-with-rest-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("push")
public Response push(YourObjectType yourDataOpbect) {

    ....

    return null;
}
```

[image]

in Here you have to put your Json string which exactly match with your object.